# Display sum of 10 input numbers but take out highest and lowest number

Tags: c#

I want to input 10 numbers and get the total sum of them if you take out the highest and lowest number that was input. So basically it'll be 8 numbers that i get the sum of when i take out the highest and lowest number that was input out of the 10. So far i can only count the total sum out of the 10 numbers, but not sure how to take out the highest and lowest. What approach could i take?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number, sum = 0, n;

            for (number = 1; number < 11; number++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
                n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                sum += n;
            }

            Points(sum);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void Points(int sum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Totalpoint is " + sum);
        }
```

Comment: You could have a collection holding all input values, then you query it in order to find the max and minimum values, remove them and then you can finally perform your sum.

Comment: @AndréB Could you give an example? I have a hard time visualizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition is additive, so you can simply remove them on the end:

```
int sum = 0;
int min = int.MaxValue;
int max = int.MinValue;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    sum += n;
    min = Math.Min(min, n);
    max = Math.Max(max, n);
}

sum -= min;
sum -= max;

Points(sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I got several good answers here with different approaches, this one was simple and easy to follow and gives me the desired result. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An easy implementation to explain my thought process, could be the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int number, sum = 0, n;

    List<int> inputNumbers = new List<int>();
    for(number = 0; number < 10; number++)
    {
        inputNumbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
    }

    // Obtain maximum and minimum values
    var maximum = inputNumbers.Max();
    var mimimum = inputNumbers.Min();

    foreach (var item in inputNumbers)
    {
        if(item == maximum)
        {
            inputNumbers.Remove(item);
            break;
        }
    }

    foreach(var item in inputNumbers)
    {
        if(item == mimimum)
        {
            inputNumbers.Remove(item);
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Sum: "+inputNumbers.Sum());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The solution is rather simple, since after populating the List with the specified 10 values, you query it to obtain the minimum and maximum values. 
When you know them, you can simply loop through the list and remove both the maximum and minimum (break is completely necessary after those operations).

Downside? In this simple implementation, you would be iterating through the List two times, which should definitely be optimized, even if for clean code sake. 
But it might the best first step to you!

Answer (score 1):

Just have two more variables to track max and min values as you read them:

```
min = Math.Min(min, n);
max = Math.Max(max, n);
```

Then, as you exit the loop, you can simply subtract those from the total sum before printing.

```
sum -= min + max;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
List<int> testNum = new List<int>();
int num = 0;
int sum = 0;
try
{
   // This will loop until you have 10 inputs
   while(testNum.Count < 10)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
       num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // Need to have the Try/Catch in case user doesn't input a number
       testNum.Add(num);
   }

   // Get the min and max values (you will need System.Linq for this)
   int minVal = testNum.Min();
   int maxVal = testNum.Max();

   // Remove the min and max values from the List
   testNum.Remove(testNum.IndexOf(minVal));
   testNum.Remove(testNum.IndexOf(maxVal));

   // Sum the remaining values up
   foreach(int n in testNum)
   {
       sum = sum + n;
   }

   return sum;

}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the input numbers in the List and sum their values excluding min and max values

```
public  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number " + i);
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            list.Add(num); //adding the input number in list
        }
        Sum(list);           
    }

  private static void Sum(List<int> list)
  {
      int max =  list.Max();
      int min = list.Min();
      int sum = list.Where(x => x != max && x != min).Sum(); //taking the sum of all values exlcuding min and max
      Console.WriteLine("Sum is " + sum);
  }
```